# How wide would my cylinder be to allow air 500m below water surface?

Tags: hard-science, underwater

I'd like my (very well funded) group of scientists to conduct an important excavation, in-situ with fully breathable air and comfort.  I realize a pipe down to the surface would require a pump and could cause issues.

What I'd like is a cylinder wide enough that there is natural ventilation, and they can continue their excavations, dry, and breathing naturally without any automated pumps, etc.

I'll handle the depth of the cylinder into the seabed later, and of course this is an expensive prospect, but basically want to have a perfectly breathable seabed at 500m depth.  **How wide would it need to be?**

PS - It's about the elevation of the dead sea.

EDIT: I am looking for an open space that allows for the free-breathing of the excavators.  Specifically the width of the air-space (I allow a conical shape of course as well).  The structural, safety and financial features are a separate question.  This is purely about breathe-ability.

[image]

Comment: I don't have a good enough visual of what you are looking for.  What does width have to do with it?  The main limit will be the incredible crushing pressures of the water at 500m, and the extraordinarily high level of risk associated with a failure of the wall.

Comment: Were you referring to the thickness of the wall, rather than the width of the cylinder?

Comment: I attempted answering, but it turns out it's more complicated than what I thought. Carbon monoxide and dioxide tends to settle. Flammable vapors might be a problem. Cold walls not helping with convection. And few more issues. Can't help, but I'd like to see a good answer that would talk about these.

Comment: @CortAmmon - no, I apologize; I aim to find an answer to how wide the airspace diameter is, to allow for natural breathing, not the structural integrity of it (which is another doozie).

Comment: @Mołot - yes, this is a difficult question with airflow and all sorts of issues.  They can reinforce the structure a thousand times over, but it needs to be natural, breathable for 2 to 7 people at a time at long duration.  Hence the hard-science tag.  I am looking forward to an answer as well as you, since it escapes me as well.

Comment: how much people and equipment(in case combustion engines) there should be. do they work day and night or 8h work day? As I undestand criteria they should not die, and as comfort something like <5000ppm TWA http://www.blm.gov/style/medialib/blm/wy/information/NEPA/cfodocs/howell.Par.2800.File.dat/25apxC.pdf  Also do u sure to not use some design improvements in you tower of Babylon$^{-1}$?  Some kind of heater at bottom could greatly improve air exchange. Also there almost 0 problem to a make airflow in 500m long, 10m wide tube as an example - how big should we start.

Comment: You will have to specify the maximum number of people located on the sea floor doing excavation, as well as if they will be doing heavy labor, since the limiting factor on the pipe dimensions will be the amount of CO2 that needs be replaced by air from the surface. If deep enough, and because CO2 is heavier than air, natural circulation will not be sufficient unless the pipe is made much larger since the CO2 will build up over time without fans to circulate it to the surface. A conical shape (unless the point is downward) is actually worse for circulation.

Comment: What's your thoughts on basic air movers, like scoops?

Comment: To clarify, this is entirely 2 to 7 people per 8-hour day, with the only equipment being hand tools (shovels and brushes), one contractor's elevator for people and light material removal.  I hadn't considered a heater, so thank you for that - one generator for lights and heat.  No other equipment.  Duration of the excavation will be a little more than six months.

Comment: Given the complexity of the physics involved, I think the [SE Physics site](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions) is a more likely place to get a good "hard science" answer.

Comment: One more issue I thought about is whether or not you know the exact diameter of your dig site. What if midway into your excavation, it is discovered the actual dig site is larger than previously thought, and hence the tower walls are too small? So, this needs to be taken into account too, otherwise the exact width might need to change. Is your excavation a few miles wide, like an old city? Or is it a small ship wreck? That will influence the answer.

Comment: What does your comment "it's about the elevation of the Dead Sea" mean? Are you saying your dig site is in the Dead Sea? What does "it" refer to?

Comment: @ThomBlairIII - I thought it would be relevant to note that the elevation equates almost the same elevation as the Dead Sea (i.e. - the dig location in this speculative science story is demonstrably livable in our world as it is, given adequate air is available without mechanical intervention)

Comment: @Mikey Ok, thank you. One question stilll left unanswered is the approximate size of the known dig site, which is important because if it is miles wide, that will definitely make calculations MUCH less critical, whereas if the site is only a 50 meters wide, there is a much lower tollerance for error.

Comment: One other resource you might consider is researching how long air lasts in scuba diving: http://scuba.about.com/od/scuba101/p/How-Long-Does-A-Scuba-Tank-Last.htm

Answer (score 7):

### Size of Site?

One important factor you have not yet provided us with is the known diameter of the excavation site. Is it miles wide, like a submerged ancient city, or is it a small ship wreck? That information can greatly effect the answer.

However, given the drawing you provided, I'm assuming it's a small site, and hence this is my thought:

### Cylindrical Tower with Ventilation Shafts in Walls

You could have a relatively narrow total radius of the tower if your cylinder's walls were hollow with wind-catching vent openings at the top and vent openings at their base:

[image]

The amount of wind caught by the ventilation shaft's openings at the top would depend on their [height above sea level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wind_gradient), since [wind speed increases as elevation increases:](https://www.classzone.com/books/earth_science/terc/content/investigations/es1702/es1702page09.cfm)

[image]

[(NOTE: 1 knot = 1.15078 mph)](https://www.google.com/search?q=convert%20knots%20to%20mph&oq=convert%20knot&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j69i64j0l4.4495j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

In order to achieve a constant influx of wind, you need to make sure your tower is tall enough to catch a constant breeze--basically a skyscraper. For this, you need to know the atmospheric properties of your site. Although you have stated it will be in the Dead Sea, the amount of wind will be influenced by any nearby geographical features, so you will have to know your exact geographical location.

Once you have this information, you can use [wind engineering formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wind_engineering) to determine how high the tower would have to be to achieve a sufficient constant influx of fresh air. You could then calculate:

- tower height
- number of ventilation shafts
- opening size of each vent mouth

Answer (score 6):

### Convection-Based Ventilation

This idea would allow you to have a tower only as wide as your dig site. The main concept is to have a solar-heated element running down the central shaft of the tower, heating the air and causing a [chimney effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_effect), sucking fresh cool air in from the side ventilation shafts:

[image]

Here is an alternate design that doesn't require hollow walls, just a simple partition down the middle of the tower:

[image]

The principle of the solar-heated element is basically the same as that used in [solar power tower plants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_power_tower), where an array of mirrors focuses sunlight on a central collection tower so that the collection tower becomes quite hot:

[image]

I think this type of design would be much more effecient and simple to design than the wind-catching skyscraper idea I proposed earlier. It also allows you to keep the tower quite small, only the size of your excavation site, hence keeping building costs low and increasing real-world feasibility.

Answer (score 4):

Thermal convection is your friend

[image]

By heating air in the center you can draw air down from the sides.

Because of thermal stacking, thermal power generation towers can be as tall as 1000 meters.

Answer (score 3):

just use mine airflow as guide. For heavy exertion humans need a bout 65 liters of fresh air a minute. if they are just walking around they need only 14. the most important factor is what kind of activity level are people doing and how many people are there. 
But in short no matter what the answer they are probably going to need a few fans.

http://www.molecularproducts.com/pdf/technical-library/A%20Guide%20to%20Breathing%20Rates%20in%20Confined%20Environments%20Technical%20Article.pdf

https://www.cdc.gov/niosh/mining/UserFiles/works/pdfs/bul589.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Really a comment but it won't fit:

1)  You're missing a big problem here--you have 5 megapascals of pressure trying to push under your cofferdam.  Water is going to seep in pretty quickly playing havoc with your request for dry.  (Oops, I originally goofed up and said 50, a zero placement error.)

2)  Temperature.  It's going to be awfully cold down there, can you say "fog"?  And "dew"?

3)  Your cylinder need to be at least 540 meters, not 500 meters--it needs to be tall enough to keep the largest rogue wave from going over the top.  (Edit:  Thinking more about this you need even more height but I don't know how much.  The 40 meters was to cover the highest of rogue waves but this isn't a ship designed to cut the water, when the water strikes a wall that wide some of it goes up.)

4)  Can you say "sea spray"?  Waves are going to hit your cylinder, some of the spray will fall inside.  You asked for dry.

Finally

5)  If you want your workers comfortable you will need to heat the work area--and that combined with a simple baffle in your cylinder will substantially cut the needed size.

Edit:  Why did I get the warning about hard science?  This is an oversize comment showing more of the problem, not an attempt to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you want to work on the seabed, 500 m down, without using either a [caisson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caisson_(engineering)) or divers, so you opt for a [cofferdam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofferdam).

You will have to pump the water out (compare [this picture](http://www.americanbridge.net/experience/experience_detail.php?prj_ab_id=PortCorl20102004081129581)), so pumping air in will be the least of your problems.

If air circulation was your only worry, consider open pit mines like this one in [Bingham Canyon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bingham_Canyon_Mine) as an upper limit on the necessary diameter.

---

Follow-Up: With a bit of googling I found [this article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/305985993_Closed_coal_mine_shaft_as_a_source_of_carbon_dioxide_emissions) about CO2 emissions from mine shafts. Obviously the shafts have no air scoops, and the emissions depend on outside air pressure. That gives you a lower limit on the diameter of a feasible shaft.

Comment: This does not meet the requirements of the [tag:hard-science] tag. You would need to compute the result, not just give general pointers.